# All projects stop work

Tags: android-studio

I have a lot of projects and all of them stop work today gives me errors on all code , the error is **default activity not found** !

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you done any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had a similar problem this helped:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

and then select

```
Invalidate and Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your androidmanifest.xml changed somehow? You need a launcher activity defined in your manifest for the app to know which activity it needs to launch.

Also, if you need help it is best to post at least some of your code as it helps us identify the problem